# Подключение приложения к базе данных MySQL

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Как лучше всего подключаться к MySQL? В Сети много материалов по этому поводу, но все они какие-то странные. Может, есть какие-нибудь рекомендации, которых нужно придерживаться, чтобы не травмировать ресурсы устройства.

Answer (score 1):

В чем их странность? Я вижу только два способа:

1. Сервер, на котором хранится БД, и через АПИ-запросы (которые нужно написать на php или другом языке, т.е. нужна некая вэб-прослойка между БД и устройством, безопасно) идет обмен данными между приложением и сервером, запись, удаление и т.д.
2. БД хранится на самом устройстве в папке, недоступной для пользователя. Обращение к БД будет уже напрямую, что небезопасно.

НО: на девайсе вряд ли вы сможете создать именно базу под мускул, т.к. нужен сервер, работающий в фоновом режиме, для доступа к БД. Т.е. лучше использовать кордату или создать .sqlite файлик, скачать либу DBManager, подключить к проекту и через обычные SQL-запросы работать с БД.